# Custom modeless dialog not showing

Tags: c++, qt, modal-dialog, qdialog, non-modal

I have to convert a modal dialog to a modeless one.

I made some changes already by referring to the Qt Documentation. I basically created two signals to detect if the dialog is accepted or rejected, and connected them using `connect()`.

I tried to show the widget using the `show()`, but the widget is not showing.

What is the mistake I am making?

```
#ifndef INDENTOPTIONS_H
#define INDENTOPTIONS_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class indentOptions;
}

class indentOptions : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit indentOptions(QWidget *parent = nullptr, int * left = nullptr, int * right = nullptr);
    ~indentOptions();
signals:
    void dialogAccepted();
    void dialogRejected();

protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent* event) override;

private slots:
    void on_buttonBox_accepted();

    void on_buttonBox_rejected();

private:
    Ui::indentOptions *ui;
    int * left;
    int * right;

};

#endif // INDENTOPTIONS_H
```

indentoptions.cpp

```
#include "indentoptions.h"
#include "ui_indentoptions.h"

indentOptions::indentOptions(QWidget *parent, int* left, int* right) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::indentOptions)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->left = left;
    this->right = right;
    setWindowTitle("Set Indentation");
    setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModality::NonModal);
}

indentOptions::~indentOptions()
{
    delete ui;
}

void indentOptions::closeEvent(QCloseEvent* event)
{

    emit dialogRejected();// Set check_b to true when the dialog is closed
    QDialog::closeEvent(event);
}

void indentOptions::on_buttonBox_accepted()
{

    int l = ui->textEdit_left->toPlainText().toInt();
    int r = ui->textEdit_right->toPlainText().toInt();
    if(l==0 && r==0){
        emit dialogRejected();
        return;
    }

    *left = l;
    *right = r;
    emit dialogAccepted();
}

void indentOptions::on_buttonBox_rejected()
{
    emit dialogRejected();
    this->close();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::on_actionIndentation_Options_triggered()
{
    int left = 0, right = 0;
    indentOptions i(this, &left, &right);
    i.show();

    connect(&i, &indentOptions::dialogAccepted, this, [this, &left, &right](){
        if(left + right <= 14){
            on_actionIncrease_Indent_triggered(left, right);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created dialog on the stack, so it's deleted after `on_actionIndentation_Options_triggered` exits. You also captured pointers to local variables inside lambda function, which will be invalid after `on_actionIndentation_Options_triggered` exits (undefined behaviour at the time lambda will be called).

Create memeber variables and getter functtions for `left` and `right` inside `indentOptions` and allocate dialog on the heap.

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_actionIndentation_Options_triggered()
{
    indentOptions* i = new indentOptions(this);
    i->show();
    connect(i, &indentOptions::dialogAccepted, this, [=](){
        int left = i->left();
        int right = i->right();
        if(left + right <= 14) {
            on_actionIncrease_Indent_triggered(left, right);
        }
        i->deleteLater();
    });
}
```

Dialogs are usually allocated on the stack because `QDialog::exec()` blocks function until dialog is accepted, so it can only work for modal dialogs.